# What could be the reason .get() to get a double doesn't work on a SimpleDoubleProperty

Tags: java, double

As per JavaDocs, [DoublePropertyBase.html#get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/property/DoublePropertyBase.html#get()) is a valid method which returns a `double`.

I'm trying to do `component.getSpace().widthProperty().get()`, where `component` is a Window, from this library: [jtcui](https://github.com/zeroeightysix/jtcui/), and widthProperty() is defined here: [Space.java#61](https://github.com/zeroeightysix/jtcui/blob/master/core/src/me/zeroeightsix/jtcui/Space.java#L61)

For some reason, Intellij IDEA says it "cannot resolve method get()", with the full error being this:

```
/home/bella/projects/guiTestKami/build/sources/main/java/me/zeroeightsix/kami/gui/Window.java:36: error: cannot access SimpleDoubleProperty
            double width = component.getSpace().widthProperty().get();
                                                             ^
  class file for javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Turns out I was missing JavaFX